# What's causing this Ruby "can't convert Mongo::Cursor into Integer" error?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am using the Mongo Ruby driver and have this block of Ruby code before and after `line 171` in my code, which is apparently the source of the error below it (the `query.each` line is line 171):

```
    query = get_callback.call( "databases", id )
    if query.count > 0
      puts query.count.inspect + " results: " + query.inspect
      res = {}
      query.each do |result|
        puts result.inspect
      end
    else
      puts "No results" + res.inspect
      res = {}
    end
```

The error:

```
1 results: <Mongo::Cursor:0x3fc15642c154 namespace='myproj.databases' @selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4fe120e4a2f9a386ed000001')} @cursor_id=>
TypeError - can't convert Mongo::Cursor into Integer:
        /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bson-1.6.4/lib/bson/byte_buffer.rb:156:in `pack'
        /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bson-1.6.4/lib/bson/byte_buffer.rb:156:in `put_int'
        /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongo-1.6.4/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:603:in `construct_query_message'
        /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongo-1.6.4/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:466:in `send_initial_query'
        /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongo-1.6.4/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:459:in `refresh'
        /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongo-1.6.4/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:128:in `next'
        /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongo-1.6.4/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:291:in `each'
        /Users/myuser/Code/myproj/my_file.rb:171:in `block in initialize'
```

My query object: `{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4fe120e4a2f9a386ed000001')}`

I have not the faintest idea what's causing this. I've verified the object I'm finding exists and the `query.count` shows that there's a result in my `Mongo::Cursor`.

I've not found any examples of the issue on Google and every Mongo/Ruby on the web I've found uses an `each` iterator just like I do. Anyone know what's the cause of this error? I notice I also get it when trying to use `to_a` to cast the collection to a JSON-usable object.

---

For what it's worth, here's the relevant part of byte_buffer.rb is below. The line with `<<` is `line 156`.

```
def put_int(i, offset=nil)
  @cursor = offset if offset
  if more?
    @str[@cursor, 4] = [i].pack(@int_pack_order)
  else
    ensure_length(@cursor)
    @str << [i].pack(@int_pack_order)
  end
  @cursor += 4
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you pass nil to a Ruby Mongo driver `limit()` method.